# Trying to find the Qt5 version of QVBoxLayout

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, pyqt5, pyqt4

Migrating a plugin and started getting the error AttributeError: module 'qgis.PyQt.QtGui' has no attribute 'QVBoxLayout' I cannot find this one in the API changes I tied using qgis.PyQt5.QtGui but that didn't work.
I thin it is usage or syntax according to this
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html the in Qt5 the QVBoxLayout usage is a bit different. I have self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Configuration) I am thinking Qt5 has a completely different way of setting ui's and there is a lot of ui settings in thsi; is there a converter out there for Qt4 to Qt5? Qgis2to3 didn't change any of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GUI objects are now in `QtWidgets` instead of `QtGui`.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
```

Comment: What I did was add QtWidgets to the end of from qgis.PyQt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets and from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout just below that. Then changed all the QtGui.QVBoxLayout() to QtWidgetrs.QVBoxLayout(). When I reinstalled the plugin QGIS threw the next set of errors. Was there a cleaner way?